# Как в QT сделать ожидание входящего http запроса (get-запроса)

Tags: qt, http, get

Всем привет.
Просьба посоветовать, каким способом в QT сделать ожидание и обработку get-запроса от браузера вида http://host:port&param=value
Важно!, требуется именно принять запрос и ответить POST-ом,
а не послать GET и ждать POST, как в QNetworkAccessManager.
Хотелось-бы вручную не разбирать http-запрос, а получить данные уже в Qt-товом конейнере.
Просьба просто посоветовать варианты, как грамотно это реализовать. В детали самого QT можно не углубляться...
Что-то туплю... Или недогоняю... Спасибо всем откликнувшимся.

Comment: для начала, в HTTP существуют *GET-запросы*, *POST-запросы* (а также другие) и ответы сервера (которые по сути не отличаются для GET и POST), так что фраза «принять запрос и ответить POST-ом, а не послать GET и ждать POST» звучит довольно абсурдно... По вопросу, в самом кьюте, реализации HTTP-сервера, само собой, нет... из сторонних проектов ококло-Qt'шной биоты на первой странице одного поисковика вылезает [этот](https://github.com/nitroshare/qhttpengine) и несколько проектов [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122508/qt-http-server)

Comment: Сасибо за подсказки. [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122508/qt-http-server) собственно мой вопрос и ответы, подтверждающие, что простых средств в Qt, для реализации такого вопроса, нет. Все равно надо делать проект, все равно разбирать все заголовки вручную... Ну тогда TcpServer/TcpSocket наше все тут...

Comment: Кстати, изначально требуемая функциональность сделана на QWebServer/Socket, и в связке с клиентским Qt-приложением работает хорошо. Компактно и без проблем.
Но возникли проблемы доступа из firefox-а по схеме **http:/ /host:port/**
Не получается.. Чего-то не хватает... Решено было посмотеть в сторону QTcpServer, но тут в _десяток строк_ не уложиться...